# Ubuntu Touch - Phone call freezing

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Over the last month or so, I have notice that (every now and then) when I come to the end of a a received call, when I come to hang up the call screen has frozen. This means that I am unable to end the call and the only way the call ends, is when the other person puts their phone down. I think this only happens when I receive a call from a private number or unknown number.

Has anyone else noticed this on their phones or is it a sign that my phone is going?

Comment: This happened again atthe end of a call from a private number. The rest of the phone is working ok and I can pan across other functions. However, I cannot end the call.